# Deleting an entire row based on the value in a cell with a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro/vba which will examine rows 12 - 451 in my excel sheet.  If Column "H" (in any of the stated rows) contains a value of zero then that row should be deleted.

The Excel will be utilized for an upload program and we cannot have any zero values in column "H"

I have a Macro recorded which populates the rows 12 - 451 (columns "A" through "H") with the required data, but am having issues with the piece of code I can add to the macro (at the end) which will loop back through and delete any row which has a value of zero in column "H".

I have tried to record the "delete" Macro but cannot figure out how to make the code loop through each row and delete those with the zero value.

- NOTE - Column "H" values will vary with numerical data which will contain zero's within that data (i.e. 100,341.00).  This value should be kept.  It is only those cells which contain ONLY a "0" which should be eliminated.  Parenthesis are NOT included in the upload sheet...

Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Always helps to show your existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GIve this a try:

```
Sub HKiller()
    For i = 451 To 12 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "H").Value = 0 Then Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note we work from bottom to top to avoid index problems.

Comment: Understood on the "Bottom to Top", that is exactly what I needed!  Thank you so much for the help! This was giving me fits for the last few days.  Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same action i.e., deleting column if any one of the two columns cell has "0" then to delete the row. I have modified the above code.  kindly suggest.

```
    Sub test()
    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long
    'LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 0 To Lastrow Step 1
        If Cells(i, "E" Or "F").Value = 0 Then Rows(i).Delete
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks